# How to create abstract structure implementations

Tags: go

I've got a slice of steps `[]*Steps` where each step has a type and a custom payload depending on it:

```
type Step struct {
  ID string
  Name string
  Type StepType // Enum: StepA | StepB
  Action StepAction // interface implemented by either ActionStepA | ActionStepB
  // Other common fields
}

// StepAction is an interface implemented by either ActionStepA | ActionStepB
type StepAction interface {}

type ActionStepA struct {FieldA string} // Fields specific to step A
type ActionStepB struct {FieldB string} // Fields specific to step B
```

Depending on the `Type`, the `Action` will be a different struct: either `ActionStepA` or `ActionStepB` which just hold their own step-specific fields.

To Execute these steps, I have a `StepExecutor` interface:

```
type StepExecutor interface {
  Execute(StepAction) error
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to have a `StepExecutor` implementation per StepType which contains the business logic and knows how to execute its type. E.g. have `StepAExecutor()` which executes `ActionStepA` and `StepBExecutor` which executes `ActionStepB`.

How can I achieve something like this in GOlang? I guess what I need is a concept similar to Abstract Classes?

```
for _, step := range steps {
   executor := getExecutorForStep(step) // returns a StepExecutor type
   executor.Execute(step.Action) 
}

// ERROR HERE: 
fun getExecutorForStep(step *Step) StepExecutor {
  switch step.Type {
     case StepA: return &StepAExecutor{}
     case StepB: return &StepBExecutor{}
  }
}
```

I tried the above but I'm getting errors as the StepExecutor "implementations" are not actually implementations as they have mismatched method signatures:

- `StepExecutor` expects `StepAction` for the `Execute` method
- `StepAExecutor` expects `ActionStepA` for the `Execute` method
- `StepBExecutor` expects `ActionStepB` for the `Execute` method

If go doesn't allow for such a case, I'm happy to redo the architecture with a proper more common one. Let me know if you have any suggestions. I understand that in golang, methods signatures must match literally - I'm just unsure how I can properly structure this problem. I might be in need of a re-architecture.

Comment: where is the error? the for loop you have above should compile, based on your type definitions

Comment: The error is to do with `getExecutorForStep` as it cannot match `StepAExecutor` with a generic `StepExecutor` because of the method signature of `Execute`. Will update the question

Comment: you can move the `Execute()` directly into the `StepAction` interface, and then simply call the `step.Execute()` in the loop

Comment: @aaronlukacs I wanted to avoid that as then I need to pass in all the dependencies to the execute method (dependencies differ between step types btw so I'll have to pass all every time) + keep business logic within the data layer

Comment: rewrite the signatures of `Step<X>Executor` to accept `StepAction` interfaces, which `ActionStep<X>` conforms to, or rearchitect. Interface implementations must be exact.

Comment: a simple solution is 1) not have `StepExecutor` depend on `StepAction`, i.e. `Execute() error`, and 2) set the `StepAction` impl into the struct inside the type switch: `case StepA: return &StepAExecutor{ Action: step.Action.(ActionStepA) }`

Comment: @blackgreen so on every step I need to create a stepExecutor which is a wrapper of the action + all of it's dependencies? I was hoping I can instantiate the executor once with all required dependencies and just use it on request. Is that not possible? What architecture would you suggest?

Comment: Remove the getExecutorForStep function and call Execute directly in the switch body. Also, you don't need a common interface for steps: https://go.dev/play/p/tFURr28-YAv. Unless you simplified the code for the question you don't even need the Executor types. Top-level functions `ExecuteStepA(ActionStepA)` etc. are enough: https://go.dev/play/p/zRBBT-VzDf1

Comment: @Peter yes, code was simplified. the idea was the that the executors (4-5) will follow the same interface (5-6 methods).